# How to add new scope for facebook app which users have already installed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

User integrated with my application and install it to his account. So there is my application right there with certain scopes - https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=business_tools&ref=settings

Now i added new scope for application (for new integration type) and would like for users to have it. So, is there is a way to add new scope for installed application for users?

I'm using facebook JS SDK to let user to login and permit scope,

```
login = function (cb) {
        var scope = 'pages_messaging, pages_manage_metadata, pages_show_list, ' +
            'pages_messaging_subscriptions, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_read_engagement;

        window.FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                setAuthData(response['authResponse']);
            }
            cb(authData);
        }, {scope: scope});
    },
```

So is this a way to force user to permit new scope fields?

Comment: Not sure where the problem is supposed to be? As soon as you call the login dialog with the newly added scope the next time, they should get asked for it … is that not working for you, or what?

Comment: (Assuming you already got your app’s use of the new permission approved in review, of course, before that you can not ask users that do not have a role in your app for it.)

Comment: Yes, i added to login FB.login - auth_type: 'reauthenticate' and switch on for application, but it doesn't recall scope - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/

Comment: Did you get those new additional permissions approved in review yet? Where does your `login` function get called, did that actually happen?